# Main breaker to sub panel trips

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, subpanel

I ran 2AWG aluminum 140’ to my backyard barn through PVC conduit. I bought a [cheap subpanel](https://a.co/d/0Wh7Te4) with seemingly positive reviews.

When I switch my 60A breaker on at my main, it immediately trips. I verified that all colors and phasing are correct. What else can I do to troubleshoot?

[image]

Comment: Take the front off of the subpanel and take pictures and upload them showing all the wiring. If all the breakers in the subpanel are off does the feed breaker still trip?

Comment: Usually if a breaker trips when turning it on, there is a short, either ground touching hot or neutral touching hot.  Imgur is down right now, so you need to check the wires from the sub to main for damage to insulation.  Give a good look at both panels for wires too close to each other.

Comment: You'll want to look into what makes a neat job of this. Your cable sheath extends into the cabinet too far, and its wires should be routed around the outside, behind the insulating partitions--not flopped over the top of everything. You run a high risk of a short with that ground there. Also, several wires (including your feeders) are bent at near-problematic radii.

Comment: Is there another location to put a ground bar in the top of this box?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks like a probable hot-ground short (to the red hot terminal block or bus bar) hiding behind the red hot and neutral wires.

[image]

If you have a multimeter, remove the feed wires from the feed end breaker and neutral bar (leave ground connected.)

Switch off or remove the breaker in the sub-panel, and run some continuity tests on the disconnected wires.  In that state, there should be no continuity (infinite resistance) between any pair of the feed wires. (hHot to hot, either hot to neutral, either hot to ground, or ground to neutral.) Test *all* of those. One is probably connected and should not be.

Answer (score 1):

I rearranged everything more neatly and it appears to have done the job. Very likely that ground was creating a short. Thanks!